# "Deployment <codeDeploy> failed. Status=Failed", While trying to deploy through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy an application via CodeDeploy , but as progressing , the stack ends up in error "Deployment d-ICC6WMBE2 failed. Status=Failed"

With no reason mention. How to debug the same.
Thanks in Advance.
PFb the template , I used for deployment:

```
Parameters:
  SSHKey:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
  CodedeployInstanceType:
    Description: "EC2 instance type for  CodeDeploy Web Servers"
    Type: String
    Default: "t2.micro"
    ConstraintDescription: "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
  PublicSubnet1: 
    Description: "The first public subnet where the Jenkins EC2 instance, ELB and CodeDeploy Web Servers will be launched"
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid Public VPC Subnet."
  PublicSubnet2: 
    Description: "The second public subnet where the ELB and CodeDeploy Web Servers will be launched"
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "Must be a valid Public VPC Subnet."
  InstanceCount : 
    Description : "Number of CodeDeploy Web Server EC2 instances"
    Type : Number
    Default : 3
    ConstraintDescription : "Must be a number between 2 and 4."
    MinValue : "2"
    MaxValue : "4"
  VpcId: 
    Description: "The VPC Id where the EC2 instances will be launched."
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: "must be the name of an existing VPC."
Mappings: 
  AWSRegionArch2AMI: 
      ap-northeast-1  : 
        AMI : "ami-08847abae18baa040" 
      ap-northeast-2  : 
        AMI : "ami-012566705322e9a8e" 
      ap-south-1        : 
        AMI : "ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19" 
      ap-southeast-1  : 
        AMI : "ami-01da99628f381e50a" 
      ap-southeast-2    :  
        AMI : "ami-00e17d1165b9dd3ec" 
      eu-central-1  : 
        AMI : "ami-0f5dbc86dd9cbf7a8" 
      eu-west-1  : 
        AMI : "ami-0bdb1d6c15a40392c" 
      eu-west-2  : 
        AMI : "ami-e1768386" 
      eu-west-3   : 
        AMI : "ami-06340c8c12baa6a09" 
      sa-east-1  : 
        AMI : "ami-0ad7b0031d41ed4b9" 
      us-east-1  : 
        AMI :  "ami-04681a1dbd79675a5" 
      us-east-2   :
        AMI : "ami-0cf31d971a3ca20d6" 
      us-west-1  :
        AMI : "ami-0782017a917e973e7" 
      us-west-2  : 
        AMI : "ami-6cd6f714"    
Resources:
  WSSG:
   Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
   Properties:
     GroupDescription: "Enable HTTP access from ELB"
     VpcId: 
       Ref: "VpcId"
     SecurityGroupIngress:
       -
        IpProtocol: "tcp"
        FromPort: "22"
        ToPort: "22"
        CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
       -
        IpProtocol: "tcp"
        FromPort: "80"
        ToPort: "80"
        SourceSecurityGroupId: 
          Ref: "ELBSG"
  ELB: 
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: "2"
        Interval: "30"
        Target: "HTTP:80/"
        Timeout: "5"
        UnhealthyThreshold: "5"
      Listeners: 
        - InstancePort: "80"
          LoadBalancerPort: "80"
          Protocol: "HTTP"
          InstanceProtocol: "HTTP"
      Subnets: 
        - 
         Ref : "PublicSubnet1"
         Ref : "PublicSubnet2"
      SecurityGroups: 
        - 
         Ref: "ELBSG"
  ELBSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Enable HTTP access from anywhere"
      VpcId: 
        Ref : "VpcId"
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - IpProtocol: "tcp"   
          FromPort: "80"
          ToPort : "80"
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
  CodeDeployTrustRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2008-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
           Sid: "1"
           Effect: Allow
           Principal:
             Service: 
               - codedeploy.amazonaws.com
           Action: 
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/" 
  CodeDeployRolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties: 
      PolicyName: CodeDeployPolicy
      PolicyDocument :
        Statement:
          -
           Effect: Allow
           Action:
             - ec2:Describe*
             - autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction
             - autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook
             - autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks
             - autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
             - autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook
             - autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat
             - Tag:getResources
             - Tag:getTags
             - Tag:getTagsForResource
             - Tag:getTagsForResourceList
           Resource: "*"
      Roles: 
        - Ref: "CodeDeployTrustRole"
  DemoApplication: 
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application 
  DemoFleet:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties:  
      ApplicationName: !Ref DemoApplication
      AutoScalingGroups: 
        - !Ref WSASG
      Deployment: 
        Description: "Initial Deployment"
        Revision: 
          RevisionType: S3
          S3Location: 
            Bucket: Fn::Join:["",["aws-codedeploy-" !Ref["AWS::Region"]]]
            BundleType: "zip"
            Key: "samples/latest/SampleApp_Linux.zip"
      DeploymentConfigName: "CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime"
      ServiceRoleArn: 
        Fn::GetAtt: ["CodeDeployTrustRole", Arn]
  InstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - 
           Effect: Allow
           Principal:
             Service:
               - ec2.amazonaws.com
           Action: 
             - sts:AssumeRole               
      Path: "/"      
  CodeDeployInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - 
          Ref: "InstanceRole"
  InstanceRolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: "InstanceRole"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - 
           Effect: "Allow"
           Action: 
              - "autoscaling:Describe"
              - "cloudformation:Describe*"
              - "cloudformation:GetTemplate"
              - "s3:Get*"
              - "s3:List*"              
           Resource: "*"
      Roles: 
        - Ref: "InstanceRole"       
  WSASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties: 
      LaunchConfigurationName: 
        Ref: "WSLaunchConfiguration"
      VPCZoneIdentifier: 
        - Ref : "PublicSubnet1"
          Ref : "PublicSubnet2"
      MinSize: '0'
      MaxSize: '4'
      DesiredCapacity:
        Ref : "InstanceCount"
      LoadBalancerNames: 
        - Ref : "ELB"
      HealthCheckType: "ELB"
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 600
      Tags: 
        - Key : "Name"
          Value: "CodeDeployDemo"
          PropagateAtLaunch: true 
    CreationPolicy: 
      ResourceSignal: 
        Count: 
          Ref: "InstanceCount" 
        Timeout: "PT15M"
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MinInstancesInService: '1'
        MaxBatchSize: '1'
  WSLaunchConfiguration: 
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [AWSRegionArch2AMI, !Ref "AWS::Region","AMI"]
      InstanceType:
        Ref: CodedeployInstanceType
      SecurityGroups: 
        - Ref: "WSSG"
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
           #!/bin/bash -xe
           sudo yum update -y
           sudo yum install -y ruby
           sudo yum install -y wget
           sudo wget https://aws-codedeploy-${AWS::Region}.s3.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/latest/install
           sudo chmod +x ./install
           sudo ./install auto
           # Start cfn-init
           /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r WSLaunchConfiguration --region ${AWS::Region}
           # Signal the status from cfn-init
           /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WSASG --region ${AWS::Region} 
      KeyName: 
        Ref: "SSHKey"
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: "CodeDeployInstanceProfile"
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
    Metadata: 
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
          services:
            sysvinit:
              codedeploy-agent:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
```

As i am new to AWS, i would need little help here

Answer (score 1):

If the stack auto rolls back, disable the rollback [1] while creating the stack, then after the stack fails, go to CodeDeploy Console and look for the deployment id under 'Deployments'. The deployment details will give you reason for failure.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-prevent-rollback-failure/

Answer (score 0):

Check the `S3Location` under the `DemoFleet` resource.

The `Bucket: Fn::Join:["",["aws-codedeploy-" !Ref["AWS::Region"]]]` isn't well formatted.

Try the following

```
DemoFleet:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
  Properties:  
    ApplicationName: !Ref DemoApplication
    AutoScalingGroups: 
      - !Ref WSASG
    Deployment: 
      Description: "Initial Deployment"
      Revision: 
        RevisionType: S3
        S3Location: 
          Bucket: !Sub 'aws-codedeploy-${AWS::Region}'
          BundleType: "zip"
          Key: "samples/latest/SampleApp_Linux.zip"
    DeploymentConfigName: "CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime"
    ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt CodeDeployTrustRole.Arn
```